# Thread-safe recursive iteration

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am implementing an Observer pattern in my C++ application. So far I have a base class defined as follows:

```
template<typename CallbackType,
         typename LockType    = utils::Lock<boost::mutex>,
         typename StorageType = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CallbackType>>>
class CallbackManager
{
    LockType mCallbackLock { "commons::CallbackManager", __FILE__, __LINE__ };
    StorageType mCallbacks;

    virtual uint64_t registerCallback( const std::shared_ptr<CallbackType>& aCallbackPtr );
    virtual bool unregisterCallback( uint64_t aCallbackId );
    void iterateSubscribers(const std::function<void(typename StorageType::value_type&)>&);
};
```

One of the key requirement is to be able to perform `registerCallback`/`unregisterCallback` calls within the `iterateSubscribers` context (recursively).

`iterateSubscribers` function performs an iterative call of `aFnc` with every callback as an argument. `aFnc` might perform `registerCallback`/`unregisterCallback` call. Current implementation written as follows:

```
void iterateSubscribers(const std::function<void(typename StorageType::value_type&)>& aFnc)
{
    decltype(mCallbacks) callbacks;

    {
        // BEGIN SCOPED LOCK
        auto lock = mCallbackLock.getScopedLock();
        boost::ignore_unused( lock ); // To supress the warning in case NoLock is used

        callbacks = mCallbacks;
        // END SCOPED LOCK
    }

    for( auto it = callbacks.begin(); it != callbacks.end(); ++it )
    {
        aFnc( *it );
    }
}
```

I am performing a copy of the callbacks container which is kinda not really good from the performance point of view but resolves two issues:

- `mCallbacks` modifications do not break a loop
- new lock acquisitions will not cause a deadlock

The trade-off is acceptable for me, I will not notify newly added subscribers and will not skip notification for recently removed subscribers.

What I can't resolve in an acceptable way is:

- Non-copyable container as a template parameter for `StorageType` will cause a compilation error in `iterateSubscribers` function

The one possible solution is to define such container or its `value_type` as a pointer, but for the reasons I cannot afford this.

I also gave a look on alternative solution - do not perform a copy, replace regular mutex with a recursive mutex and perform all calls under the lock held, but it has one problem. Once element will be added or deleted, the loop will be broken:

```
for( auto it = callbacks.begin(); it != callbacks.end(); ++it )
```

Is there any other technique/ideas to achieve desired behavior?

EDIT:

I went by the road of the refactoring. Changing legacy callback containers value_type from the copy of the callback to the shared_ptr. That allowed me to copy the container and to not rely on the TriviallyCopyable state of the underplaying value_type.

Comment: I think the copying way is rather sound. To minimize performance drop, you might want to avoid dynamic memory as much as possible (0 or 1 allocations, no runtime polymorphism or else with shared pointers to the actual observers) and make sure your observers are as light as possible.  I worked once with observers where the callback was actually the best place to decide that the observer was not needed anymore and I believe we implemented something similar.

Comment: Can you show example of non-copyable container you want to handle ? (`registerCallback` should handle it logically).

Comment: registerCallback implementation is a bit more complex, it is uses pure virtual addCallback function which overloaded by derivative class who knows how to handle those custom containers. I can't paste the implementation of the non-copyable container as it is too big, the point is, it is user written with deleted copy constructor. That is a legacy code too hard to rewrite.

Comment: @stefaanv Overall, solution seems fine indeed. But how to deal with those un-copyable containers? That is my problem.

Comment: Should `callbacks` be of type of `mCallback` ? Could it be always `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CallbackType>>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 No, they can't. 

I went by the long road and refactored all the legacy code making callback containers to take a shared_ptr of the callback instead of the deep copy of the callback object. That resolved my problem with copying.